# Is there a solution to stopping the browser from loading at a random position other than using scrollTo?

Tags: reactjs

I'm assuming this happens due to certain components taking longer to render on occasion, causing the browser to scroll to its position when it eventually renders?

I've searched around and tried using a scrollTo(0, 0) function at the end of my app.js, but is this the best way to deal with this issue? It works on most browsers but doesn't solve the problem on Firefox.

Here is the main app function that calls all the react components:

```
 function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      
        <ParaDiv>

          <Nav />
          <Fade>
            <Splash />
          </Fade>

        </ParaDiv>

        <Section2 />       
        <Card1></Card1>

        <Fade>
          <Popular />
        </Fade>    

    </div>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several reasons why that happens, and it could be a symptom of a much bigger problem which can cause serious performance issues down the road. You can use tools like React DevTools/Profiler and see what components are causing unnecessary rendering, and then try and use hooks like useCallback/useMemo to solve that. Using Styled components within the functional component can cause similar behavior, even some css styling can cause that as well. I think it's better to find the root cause rather than look for a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using skeleton loaders instead, it is better practice.

Simple example found on Google:
https://codepen.io/ishaqzain/pen/yRMQOd

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
// forked from https://codepen.io/viktorstrate/pen/yoBRLy

$base-color: #F4F4F4
$shine-color: rgba(229,229,229,0.8) 
$animation-duration: 2.0s
$avatar-offset: 52 + 16

// this unfortunately uses set px widths for the background-gradient, I never got around to changing it to work with all widths :(
@mixin background-gradient
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $base-color 0px, $shine-color 40px, $base-color 80px) 
  background-size: 600px
  
body
  margin: 0

.container
  height: 100vh
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  
.post
  width: 220px
  height: 80px
  
  .avatar
    float: left
    width: 52px
    height: 52px
    background-color: #ccc
    border-radius: 25%
    margin: 8px
    
    @include background-gradient
    animation: shine-avatar $animation-duration infinite ease-out
    
  .line
    float: left
    width: 140px
    height: 16px
    margin-top: 12px
    border-radius: 7px
    
    @include background-gradient
    animation: shine-lines $animation-duration infinite ease-out
    
  .avatar + .line
    margin-top: 11px
    width: 100px
    
  .line ~ .line
    background-color: #ddd
 
@keyframes shine-lines
  0%
    background-position: -100px
  
  40%, 100%
    background-position: 140px

@keyframes shine-avatar
  0%
    background-position: -100px + $avatar-offset
  
  40%, 100%
    background-position: 140px + $avatar-offset
```

Comment: I tried adding a container with a height of 100vh around the code I just added to the question which didn't seem to solve the problem. Is this relevant to how React renders components?

Comment: Have a look here: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a few other things to mention, not actually an answer:

1. The scrollToTop should happen while the content is relatively "fixed", so nothing slides around that can change document height while scrolling up
2. you have to scroll to the top while loading new content, because if it's there you already want the user to be right there
3. you don't want the user to look at the "old" content while scrolling up, so you could make it disappear of put a modal layer over it, that prevents the user from clicking around
4. to show something like the skeleton loader from @Dorwey is a good idea, but that has to happen right after the click and then scrolling up